# How to put symbol on top of another one?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm trying to replicate this formula:

> [image]

Could you please help me put `y=(1-\gamma)x+\gamma x` as in the picture?

My attempt: `M=\max _{x, s, y \in C} \frac{2}{\gamma^{2}}\left(f(y)-f(x)-\nabla f(x)^{T}(y-x)\right)`

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\substack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
M=\max _{\substack{x, s, y \in C\\y=(1-\gamma)x +\gamma s}}
   \frac{2}{\gamma^{2}}\left(f(y)-f(x)-\nabla f(x)^{T}(y-x)\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you think that using `\mathclap` for the second line of the substack would look better, typographically?

Comment: @Bernard -  I thought about applying `\mathclap` to the second line as well; however, the result isn't great as the `\gamma s` term ends up almost touching the `\gamma^2` term in the fraction.

Comment: @Bernard I tried to mimic the OP's question, though as Mico notes, in this case, `\mathclap` doesn't look too hot.

Comment: If you add `\:` on each side of the first line, I find it OK

Answer (score 3):

Another option from `amsmath` is the `\overset{above}{below}` macro. There is a caveat, though, you have to explicitely add `\scriptstyle` to the first argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
M=\max_{\overset{\scriptstyle x, s, y\in C}{y=(1-\gamma)x+\gamma s}}
   \frac{2}{\gamma^2} \left(f(y)-f(x)-\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: It seems to me that the size of `x, s, y \in C` is smaller than `y=(1-\gamma)x +\gamma s` :(

Comment: Yes, that's a caveat, you have to explicitely add `\scriptstyle`. I edited my answer.